# Building SQL deployment script

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, database-schema

I was wondering if there is any civilized method of assembling SQL deployment scripts out of parts. Like if you've got ten files with stored procedure definitions (it's easier to change and debug them that way), a list of tables with fields and three sets of initial data (for every client). Or from any other set that's more complex and organised.

Because changing schema file that is 200k big and grows is very hard.

I personally ended up writing some PHP scripts that assembled whole file for me. So, the stored proc file looks like this:

```
--<?php $procParams = "@UserLogin varchar(50), @RightName varchar(100)"; ?> 
--<?php if (!defined('PROC_INNER')) { ?> 
if exists (select * from sys.objects where object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'DepriveUserRight') and type in (N'P', N'PC'))
begin
  drop procedure DepriveUserRight
end;
go

--returns all the object types
create procedure DepriveUserRight @UserLogin varchar(50), @RightName varchar(100)
as
--<?php } ?> 
  declare @RightId int
  select @RightId = RightID from [Right] where RightName = @RightName

  exec DepriveUserRightById @UserLogin, @RightId
--<?php if (!defined('PROC_INNER')) { ?> 
go

exec DepriveUserRight 'mgr', 'save_login'
--<?php } ?>
```

I've also included some semantics, such as type building from a table definition. Tables look like this:

```
 addTable('LinkObjectType');
?>
 LinkObjectTypeID int not null identity primary key,
 LinkObjectTypeName varchar(100) not null,
 LinkObjectTypeData varchar(250) null
<?php
 endTable();
```

And the command I execute is `php realSchema.sql > bin/realSchema.sql`

(I use MS SQL, and my application is not Web one, if it matters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you get a design tool to manage your database, one that creates a script for you.

Personally I use [Dezign for Databases](http://datanamic.com/dezign/index.html) from [Datanamic](http://datanamic.com) as, for the money, it's an excellent tool.

Another I have used, which is open source, is [DBDesignerFork](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdesigner-fork/). It also can reverse engineer your database to make it easier to create the model.

Of course these tools will not be able to help with the user data scripts but it shouldn't be a problem for the person setting up the DB to run the table creation script and then import the data.

Comment: I generally use Redgate for deploying design changes quickly and easily. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-comparison-bundle/

Comment: The Redgate tools are also excellent and probably more suited to patching a DB and data. I forgot about SQL packager.